# Error: sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function

Tags: karma-jasmine, unittest, jasmine, angular15

He realizado este Unit Test. Es bastante sencillo pero recibo continuamente el error: `TypeError: this.sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function` y no puedo encontrar el problema. Os importaria echarle un ojo?

```
it('should sanitize the style and return SafeStyle', () => {
      let sanitizer: DomSanitizer = TestBed.inject(DomSanitizer);

      const imageName = 'your-image.jpg';
      const props = 'width: 100%; height: auto;';
      const expectedSafeStyle: SafeStyle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${component.baseImgPath}${imageName}) ${props}`);
  
      const safeStyle = component.sanitizeStyle(imageName, props);
  
      expect(safeStyle).toEqual(expectedSafeStyle);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema. Para asegurarme que tanto component como test usan el mismo sanitizer he optado finalmente por injectarlo en una funcion que he creado para emular el comportamiento del componente.

```
it('should sanitize the style with default props', () => {
      const imageName = 'image.jpg';
      const baseImgPath = 'path/';
      const expectedSafeStyle: SafeStyle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${baseImgPath + imageName}) `);
  
      const result = sanitizeStyle(imageName, undefined, sanitizer, baseImgPath);

    expect(result).toEqual(expectedSafeStyle);
    });

function sanitizeStyle(imageName: string, props: string = '', sanitizer: DomSanitizer, baseImgPath: string): SafeStyle {
  let url = baseImgPath + imageName;
  return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${url}) ${props}`);
}
```